# Force HTTPS redirection with AWS Classic Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, apache2, amazon-elb

I have a website in AWS hosted in an EC2 instance. I successfully configured SSL certificate via Classic Load Balancer and I can ONLY access https version of my website.

I am getting request timed out on the HTTP version of my website.

What I want to do is to permanently redirect the traffic from HTTP to my HTTPS site.

I don't want to do it via `.htaccess` since AWS does not recommend it.

I've been trying different configs in my 
**/etc/apache2/site-available/000-default.conf** file but still doesn't work.

Here are some configs I tried

this is the first one

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =replaced-this-with-my-domain.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>
```

and this is another one

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Redirect / https://replaced-this-with-my-domain.com/

</VirtualHost>
```

Do I need to edit other configurations other than the **/etc/apache2/site-available/000-default.conf** file?

Comment: Hi Kim, I think this should be fine. Also, just a word of caution, please do enable Stickiness on your ELB so that you can prevent `TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error on your application.

Comment: @PiyushBaderia, I enabled stickiness but i'm not sure if i did it correctly. I tried enabling stickiness for port 80 and 443, but now I get error 503 for both HTTP and HTTPS

Comment: Would it be possible for you to send me the config that you are using on your load balancer to enable stickiness? I enabled Load Balancer Generated Cookie Stickiness with an expiration period of 3600 seconds (1 hour) and it worked perfectly for me.